Two similar formulas for ellipse circumference?
Does
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x}dx=
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x}dx
$$
The right expression is the ellipse circumference.

If $a=b$, then they are equal.

Hint: does rotating an ellipse through $90^\circ$ change its circumference?

Thanks Chris. I understand now...

Useful facts

$\displaystyle \int_0^\alpha f(x) \, dx= \int_0^\alpha f(\alpha-x) \, dx$

$\displaystyle\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2}-x \right) \equiv \cos x$

$\displaystyle \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2}-x \right) \equiv \sin x$

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 x+b^2\sin^2 x} \, dx=4\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 x+b^2\sin^2 x} \, dx$



Yes, the two expressions are equal. The left hand side is simply circumference of a ellipse that is rotated 90 degrees from the ellipse represented on the right hand side.
